# List of hooks inhibited by inhibit-modification-hooks

Tags: buffers, hooks, text-properties, documentation, overlays

The documentation of `inhibit-modification-hooks` states

```
Non-nil means don't run any of the hooks that respond to buffer changes.

This affects before-change-functions and after-change-functions,
as well as hooks attached to text properties and overlays.
Setting this variable non-nil also inhibits file locks and checks
whether files are locked by another Emacs session, as well as
handling of the active region per select-active-regions.
```

Besides `before-change-functions` and `after-change-functions`, how can I get a list of all "hooks attached to text properties and overlays"? Are these the only hooks that `inhibit-modification-hooks` inhibits or are there others? For example, wouldn't `first-change-hook` be inhibited as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An overlay can have property `modification-hooks`, which specifies particular hooks.

Buffer text or a string can have text property `modification-hooks`, which is similar but slightly different.

See the Elisp manual:

- Node [Overlay Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlay-Properties.html)
- Node [Special Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html)

There you'll see how `inhibit-modification-hooks` relates to these properties.